Combined table in R: entries from first table nested under each entry of second table
I have the following two tables, ProteinList and PeptideList. There are multiple peptides for each protein. I want to make a combined table where each list of peptides is nested under the protein entry. I'm new to R and tried reading some guides on rbind but I don't even know how to approach this problem.
ProteinList <- data.frame(Proteins = c(A1INK5, K1SNC9), Abundance = c(67, 25))

ProteinList
Proteins  Abundance
A1INK5    67
K1SNC9    25

PeptideList <- data.frame(MasterProtein = c(A1INK5, A1INK5, A1INK5, K1SNC9, K1SNC9), Peptides = c(VSAITLEDGVYR, TLEDGVY, LEDGVYRTD, KNSLRGFDDDE, MKLSFYHPNS), Positions = c([1-65], [53-78], [70-88], [30-42], [41-55]))

PeptideList
MasterProtein   Peptides           Positions
A1INK5          VSAITLEDGVYR       [1-65]
A1INK5          TLEDGVY            [53-78]
A1INK5          LEDGVYRTD          [70-88]
K1SNC9          KNSLRGFDDDE        [30-42]
K1SNC9          MKLSFYHPNS         [41-55]


How can I combine them as the following:
ProteinPeptideList:
Proteins  Abundance
A1INK5    67
          Peptides        Positions
          VSAITLEDGVYR    [1-65]
          TLEDGVY         [53-78]
          LEDGVYRTD       [70-88]
K1SNC9    25
          Peptides        Positions
          KNSLRGFDDDE     [30-42]
          MKLSFYHPNS      [41-55]

I'm sorry, I'm fairly new to R and I'm not sure how to even attempt this problem. I tried some basic commands but didn't get anything close to what I'm trying to get.

Did you try merge? merge(ProteinList, PeptideList, by.x = "Proteins", by.y = "MasterProtein")

If you work with big data frames data.table package is best option:
library(data.table)
ProteinList <-
  data.table(Proteins = c("A1INK5", "K1SNC9"),
             Abundance = c(67, 25))
PeptideList <-
  data.table(
    MasterProtein = c("A1INK5", "A1INK5", "A1INK5", "K1SNC9", "K1SNC9"),
    Peptides = c(
      "VSAITLEDGVYR",
      "TLEDGVY",
      "LEDGVYRTD",
      "KNSLRGFDDDE",
      "MKLSFYHPNS"
    ),
    Positions = c("[1-65]", "[53-78]", "[70-88]", "[30-42]", "[41-55]")
  )

ProteinPeptideList <- merge(ProteinList, PeptideList, by.x = "Proteins", by.y = "MasterProtein")

Output:
> ProteinPeptideList
Key: <Proteins>
   Proteins Abundance     Peptides Positions
     <char>     <num>       <char>    <char>
1:   A1INK5        67 VSAITLEDGVYR    [1-65]
2:   A1INK5        67      TLEDGVY   [53-78]
3:   A1INK5        67    LEDGVYRTD   [70-88]
4:   K1SNC9        25  KNSLRGFDDDE   [30-42]
5:   K1SNC9        25   MKLSFYHPNS   [41-55]

